# PhoneGap project on cloud9 IDE

Tags: cordova, cloud9-ide

Hi I tried searching for some kind of step by step tutorial to setup a phonegap project for android/iOS on Cloud IDE...  can some one guide or point to a link.

1 - How can I get Android SDK and ADT get running on cloud 9 ide?

2- Can I have iOS sdk on cloud 9 ide and develop for iphone?

Answer (score -2):

[Phonegap tool Cloud9 IDE introduction and use](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://mobile.51cto.com/web-322270.htm&prev=/search?q=cloud9%2bphonegap&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS497US497&biw=1280&bih=675)

Originally in chinese I haven't tried it yet but it seems promising.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.

Comment: This link contains no information about phonegap or android. It is just an explanation of how to use cloud9ide locally, instead of through c9.io